# Data level / ado.net entity data model missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've seen a few threads on this subject but none of which solved the issue for me.  I'm fairly new to the technology which makes it a little more difficult to solve.  I moved from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017.  When I create a new project I select **Visual C#/.NET Core** and then **ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core**).  Next page is **ASP.NET Core 1.1/Web Application**.

On the Models folder, I select Add/New Item to add a model.  The screen that pops up should have a Data level so I can pick ado.net entity data model.  That is missing.  Bottom line is the wizard is nowhere to be found.  Am I missing a NuGet package?  Before anyone asks, Yes, I used individual components at installation and all the tools have been loaded.

Comment: Just an update that might help... I am using a previous project as a template.  It was created in VS 2015 before the latest updates to CORE.  I can delete the model and create a new one using the wizard using VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem for the past 4 days, and I found a solution. The problem stems from you using Visual C#/.NET Core and not Visual C#/.NET Framework. Apparently the Core components do not implement anything past Framework 2.0, which is incompatible with both EntityFramwork and ADO.NET.

1. First start a new project of type Visual C#/ .NET Framework console.
2. Then connect your database via the View > Server Explorer tab.
3. Once you've connected, right click on your project and choose Properties, and make sure it says Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later.
4. Then right click your project and Manage NuGet Packages, and install EntityFramework for your project.
5. Finally right click your project > Add > New Item > Data > ADO.NET Framework object, and follow the wizard.

I hope this gets you on track. I wish there had been an answer for this a week ago for me, as this was a very aggravating problem. Every solution I could find was for a different problem that simply looked on the surface to be the same.

Comment: Edit, I assumed you wanted a Console app, the important point is you do not want a .NET Core app for what you are doing.